# How to replace the last line of a string

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to replace the last line of a string only from the value of a textarea? The string I will be changing will be dynamic! This code is in jquery!

```
var $textarea = $('#textarea');
var textarea_val = $textarea.val()
var value_list = textarea_val.split("\n");
var string_to_change = "lol"; //This value is dynamic
var last_value = value_list[invite_value.length - 1];


$textarea.val(textarea_val.replace(last_value, string_to_change)) //This is where I am stuck at!
```

The last piece of code will replace every instance of the last_value of the textarea_val which is what I want to prevent and only replace the last line of the textarea value!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the last value in array :) and then join it again

```js
$('.replace').click(function() {
  var txt = $('#textarea');
  var text = txt.val().trim("\n");
  var valuelist = text.split("\n");
  var string_to_replace = "lol";
  valuelist[valuelist.length-1] = string_to_replace;
  txt.val(valuelist.join("\n"));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea">

</textarea>
<button class="replace">Replace</button>
```

Comment: It replace all text if you doesn't use `enter`.

Comment: well @Mohammad if you don't use enter than all text is one line ?

Comment: I tested it and this is exactly what i was looking for! thanks @MarkoMackic

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last element from array and then add a new element and change the textarea value

```js
$('.change').click(function() {
  var txt = $('#textarea');
  var valuelist = txt.val().split("\n");
  var string_to_replace = "lol";
  valuelist.pop();
  valuelist.push(string_to_replace);
  txt.val(valuelist.join("\n"));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea">

</textarea>
<button class="change">change</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the last item in the array and then join the array back to a string and set the value back to the textarea

```
var value_list = textarea_val.split("\n");
var string_to_change = "lol"; //This value is dynamic
value_list[value_list.length -  1] = string_to_change

$textarea.val(value_list.join("\n"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var position = $textarea_val.lastIndexOf(last_value);
$textarea.val($textarea_val.substring(0, position) + string_to_change + $textarea_val.substring(position + last_value.length);
```

Something like this?